# How to use a particular brownie recipe for s'mores

Tags: brownies

I've got a particular brownie recipe that I swear by.  I'd like to add to it to make it a s'mores recipe.  I've got some ideas on how to do it but am unsure of the times and temps.

The brownie recipe:

- 2 sticks of unsalted butter
- 8 oz bittersweet bakers chocolate
- 1 C white sugar
- 1 C dark muscovado sugar
- 4 eggs
- 1/2 tsp salt
- 2 tsp vanilla
- 1 C AP flour

Double boil the sugars, chocolate and butter til barely melted.  Cool slightly.

Blend eggs, salt and vanilla.  Introduce eggs and chocolate mix slowly til mixed.  Fold in flour.

The recipe calls for it to be baked at 350° for ~35 minutes til the top is cracked and shiny

**What I'd Like To Add**

- Honey graham crumbles
- Mini marshmallows
- A very viscous caramel topping

My thought is to:

- instead of 35 @ 350, shorten the time to 30 minutes
- start at 350 for 15 minutes
- cook at 400 for 15 minutes (to cook the tops more stiffly, to hold up to the toppings
- put Graham crumbles and marshmallows on top, cook for an additional time (not sure how long)
- dot with caramel and broil for a few minutes

This is my best guess now.  I'm looking for some guidance on whether this approach looks solid and also some validation on the timing.

Comment: Viscosity is often a function of temperature, so putting it on hot should be easier than cold.

Comment: Hi Jason, when I saw the title, I expected it to be about pairing the brownies with other flavors (which was really unfortunate, because that would have been closable). So I changed the title, it now should reflect better what you are exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Taking some direction from my business manager/board of director/wife, I went in a different direction, and I think it worked out well.

Recipe:

1. I poured the original brownie recipe in the pan, and poured Graham crumbles over the batter.  I then mixed the Graham into the top layer of the batter.  Cook at 350 for 35 minutes.
2. Take pan out, cover with mini marshmallows, and 1 Tbsp scoops of the thick caramel sauce.  Cook for an additional 6-7 minutes.
3. Kill the oven, and keep it open slightly.  Broil the pan (it was at middle level) and watch until it gains golden color.

Results?  Everyone who's had it said they enjoyed it.  The only thing I'd do differently would be to let it brown for a bit longer.

[image: S'mores Brownies]

Comment: If anyone does this on their own… use a metal pan.  Pyrex and other ceramics don’t always do so well under a broiler

Comment: I have an aluminum snake pan.  So every brownie is an edge.